# geom_bar stack via alpha, not fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

It appears that when creating a stacked bar plot in ggplot, the automatic stacking variable is the fill. Is it possible to use any other option such as alpha?

I want to be able to specify my fill colors with a certain variable that I do not want stacked. Any advice is appreciated!

Here is some code for what I have right now. I basically want each bar to filled via the community and detect/non-detect to be stacked and indicated via alpha or color:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(c(rep("A", times=6), rep("B", times=6), rep("C", times=6), rep("D", times=6)),
             rep(c("Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3"), times=2),
             c(rep("Detect", 3), rep("Non-Detect", 3)),
             c(75,52,56.3,25,48,43.7,
               65.8,56.8,35.7,34.2,43.2,64.3,
               93.5,92.6,82.9,6.5,7.4,17.1,
               58.3,50.5,46.4,41.7,49.5,53.6))
colnames(dat) <- c("community", "year", "detection", "percent.value")

ggplot(data=dat,
       mapping=aes(x=community, y=percent.value, fill = detection)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + 
  ylab("Frequency")+
  facet_wrap(.~year)
```

[Example barplot from code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYu5E.png)

Comment: Does `fill = community, alpha = detection` not do what you want?  I may be misunderstanding your desired output.

Comment: you're right it worked this time. weirdly didnt work last time I tried it. Thanks!